# Break out of For loop for invalid image link Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a book with the chapter's contents via images. Images links are in below manners:

`https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/1.jpg
https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/2.jpg
https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/3.jpg
.
.
.`

Not sure how many image links per chapter. I am creating a list of images using a loop. As it iterates and finally image is not found, it will display a button using`errorWidget` for next chapter and should break out of the loop. With below implementation Images are being displayed correctly but not breaking out of the loop and multiple buttons are created.

Edit: I am now checking for image validation at the end. Now it displays only one image but prints `200` (statuscode) until once invalid and breaks out of loop.

```
 createBook() async {
    for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
      bool imageEnd = false;
      String imageUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/'+i+'.jpg';
      bookList.add(CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        placeholder: (context, url) => Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
          imageEnd = true;
          return BtnNextChapter();
          },
      ));
      if(imageEnd){
        break;
      }
      final response = await http.get(imageUrl);
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        break;
      }
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In your original code, if you comment out the statement that returns the button method, does the break then exit the loop? Also, suggest you put a couple of print statements in at strategic points to see what is happening.

Comment: The line `imageEnd = true;` is being triggered but its too late. List of all 100 images have already been added to bookList. Check for screenshot I've added.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is happening now. However, if you are able to break out of the loop at the correct point ie. the first time it fails to find an image, then why don't you add the button to the bookList outside of the loop instead of in the errorWidget block.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you should have a way to know how many books are there per chapter and should iterate those many times. However to fix your code, try the below.

```
  createBook(){
    for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
      final imageUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/'+i+'.jpg';
      final response = await http.get(imageUrl);
      print(response.statusCode);

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        bookList.add(BtnNextChapter());
      } else{
        bookList.add(CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
        );
      }
     }
   }
```

With the above code, you will miss the images if there are more than 100 migaes in any chapter.

Comment: nope, this didn't even display an image. Loop continued though.

Comment: Could you update, what exactly not working? Because I see this code doesn't change the display widgets of your code. SO it should work

Comment: It is not displaying any widgets whether it is images or button.